# Copy one row to another row value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using Windows form (Vb.net & Datagridview)

Checkbox is using in datagridview row.  I want to copy the selected row to new row.

For Example

```
ID Value Checkbox

001 100 Checked
002 200 Checked
003 250 Unchecked
```

Then i try to copy, then it should show as

```
ID Value Checkbox

001 100 Checked
002 200 Checked
003 250 Unchecked
001 100 Checked
002 200 Checked
```

Tried Code.

```
 For i As Integer = grvList.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If grvList.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then
                For j As Integer = 0 To grvList.Rows(i).Cells.Count - 1
                    MsgBox(grvList.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value)
                Next
            End If
 Next
```

'

```
grvlist - Datagridview
cells(0) - checkbox used
```

The above code is working for if checkbox checked then it is taking the current row value.  But i want to add new row, to copy all the current row values.  How to do it.

Need Vb.net code help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView has a built in copy function that should work.

EDIT: AddCopy doesn't work as advertised, it inserts an empty row with the same style as the source row.  We have to manually copy the cell data over to the new row.  Updated code below.

```
For i As Integer = grvList.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If grvList.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then

            Dim NewRowIndex as integer = grvList.Rows.AddCopy(i)

            For j = 0 To (grvList.ColumnCount - 1)
                grvList.Rows(NewRowIndex).Cells(j).value = _ 
                                           grvList.Rows(i).Cells(j).value
            Next
        End If
Next
```